# An array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct

How is an array of structures created in C without knowing the eventual amount of structures to be stored in the array?

I would like to loop in a for loop,  create a tempStruct set its variables, add this to an array and then loop again, creating a new tempStruct and adding it to the array.

Im having some issues wrapping my head around how this is done in C while trying to relate from objective C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamically allocated arrays (using `malloc`) can be reallocated (using `realloc`).

Therefore the solution will look something like this:

1. `malloc` initial array (arbitrary size)
2. while still space in array, add structures
3. when array full, `realloc` to bigger size
4. goto 2

Comment: This is great, my issue is the syntax and accessing this data. Are the structs setup as pointers and the pointer added to the array? How are elements accessed in this array? array[i] or using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: You can have either an array of structs or an array of pointers to structs, and you can access elements of the array either through pointers or indices. array[i] *is* pointer arithmetic -- it is equivalent to *(array + i).

Comment: That's quite simple. If you have an array of pointers to structures, then you will be allocating both the array and the structures and adding the structures into the array as pointers. If you have an array of structures, you only allocate the array. `array[i]` is defined as `*(array+i)`, there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is HOW do I declare an array of structs? This was my question. :)

Comment: Since you will be using `malloc` to dynamically allocate the memory, simply `struct my_personal_struct *variable;`

Comment: Thanks. I have the following album *albumArray = malloc(numberOfStructs * sizeof(album)); I typedef my struct to album. So when I first malloc this should numberOfArrays be 0 or 1? and how do I access elements in this array later? albumArray[i]? when adding to this array, do I add using albumArray[numberOfStructs] = &tempAlbum; I increment the numberOfStructs at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Your first `malloc` should allocate some reasonable amount (totally depends on the application, but 10 is a good number to start with). Malloc is slow and too many reallocations can slow down your code significantly. You should probably read up on pointers and arrays, you seem to be very confused. Assuming that `tempAlbum` is a variable of the type `album`, `&tempAlbum` is a pointer to `album`. Since `albumArray[x]` is equivalent to `*(albumArray+x)`, that is take pointer and dereference it, you can't assing `&tempAlbum` into it (since it is a pointer).

Comment: Ok. I dont know why I am cofusing myself with this concept. so I add to the array with plain tempAlbum?

Comment: Yes, you assign album into album.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I think my confusion comes down to this. If I create a struct Album e.g. Album *tempAlbum, I can access this using just tempAlbum, same as obj C, my problem in C is when I need an array of structs. Does this require that I declare the type and then use double ** e.g. Album **albumArray ? And then add to album array using albumArray[i] = tempAlbum? so double ** allows one to access the array using [i] ? My issue is just understanding the C syntax to create an array of a type? is it double **

Comment: `int x;` is a variable of type `int`, `int *x;` is a pointer to variable of type x, therefore you can do something like this `int x; int *y = &x;` (y points to the location of x) or `int *x = malloc(int*10);` (x points to the location of the dynamically allocated array of integers). `int **x;` is a pointer to pointer, used for example when you want to pass a pointer into a function for modification, or for an array of pointers or array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a double linked list which points to parent and child

```
struct list{
 list* next;
 list* prev;
 special_data* data;
}
```

easy to do and flexible

Answer (score 0):

You can use [malloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc) to create your structure.

Edit:  The following demonstrates one way to do what you're asking by creating a linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int data;
  void* next;
} tempStruct;

#define NUM_STRUCTS 4

int main(void) {
  tempStruct* cur_ptr;
  tempStruct* root_ptr;
  int i;

  root_ptr = malloc(sizeof(tempStruct));
  root_ptr -> data = 0;
  root_ptr -> next = NULL;
  cur_ptr = root_ptr;
  for (i = 1; i < NUM_STRUCTS; i ++ ) {
    tempStruct* new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(tempStruct));
    new_ptr -> data = i;
    new_ptr -> next = NULL;
    cur_ptr -> next = new_ptr;
    cur_ptr = cur_ptr -> next;
  }

  cur_ptr = root_ptr;
  while (cur_ptr != NULL) {
    printf("cur_ptr -> data = %d\n", cur_ptr -> data);
    cur_ptr = cur_ptr -> next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you really want to create something that acts more like an array, you'll need to allocate all your memory at the same time, using something like:

```
the_data = malloc(NUM_STRUCTS * sizeof(tempStruct);
```

Then you'll have to access the data with the dot operator (i.e. '.' (no quotes in your code).

Comment: Great. I want to do that, but am confused when trying to link all of these concepts. How are structures added to the array then? and how are the elements accessed?

Comment: Try to keep the concepts separate. You already know how elements of an array are accessed -- nothing new there. To maintain a variable length array in C, you must manually maintain three variables -- a pointer to the array, the length of the array, and the allocation size of the array. To add an element, just increase the length and store the new element ... but if the length becomes larger then the allocation size, you have to realloc the array to make it bigger -- either by a fixed increment or by doubling. If this seems incredibly primitive compared to other languages -- well, it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an array in C without knowing number of it's members up front.
Your options for adding are:

- (Faster) Create new array with +1 element, copy entire array and add new element to the end
- (Better) Create your own implementation of linked list ([Linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)) which will dynamically allocate memory for each new member.

Comment: Usually you double the size of the array.

Comment: No, you can create an array with a default number of elements, and then [realloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) to increase (Muggen's right, usually double) the size later.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct foo {int bar;};

size_t i = 0, n = 8;
struct foo *arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);

int bar;

while ((bar = get_next_bar()) != -1) {
    if (++i == n) { // no room for new element; expand array
        arr = realloc(arr, n *= 2);
        if (arr == NULL) abort; // see note below.
    }
    arr[i] = (struct foo){bar};
}
```

The number of assigned elements in the array is `i+1`.  Don’t forget to `free()` the array when you’re done with it.

Note:  In real programs you generally do not do `p = realloc(p, s)` directly.  Instead you assign the result of `realloc()` to a new pointer, then do error detection & handling *before* clobbering your original pointer.

Comment: Shouldnt it be malloc(n * sizeOf foo)?

Comment: @alJaree: That would be `malloc(n * sizeof(struct foo))`.  (Note the difference between `sizeof expression` & `sizeof(type)`.)  Either way will work, and both are popular, but my preference is the way I’ve posted it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I wrote foo assuming the struct is typedef to foo. :)

Comment: @alJaree: Then it’s `malloc(n * sizeof *arr)` _vs._ `malloc(n * sizeof(foo))`.